# How to compute the following recursive formula?

Tags: recursion, catalan-numbers

Given:

- $f(1) = 1$
- $f(2) = 1$
- $f(k) = f(k-1)\cdot f(1) + f(k-2)\cdot f(2) + ... + f(2)\cdot f(k-2) + f(1)\cdot f(k-1)$

How does one compute the non recursive formula for $f(k)$ ?

Comment: no idea. Find, say, $f(3), f(4), f(5)$ and see if there is anything interesting about them.

Comment: Did and still doing that. But there should be a technique for solving problems like that, shouldn't it?

Comment: Well, the fact that they are being multiplied and added together makes it a tad difficult.

Comment: This problem can be solved using generating functions. You'll end up finding that $f(k)$ is the $x^k$ coefficient in the Taylor series for $\tfrac{1}{2} - \sqrt{\tfrac{1}{4}-x}$.

Comment: These are [Catalan numbers](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C2%2C5%2C14%2C42%2C132%2C429%2C1430%2C4862&language=english&go=Search).

Comment: @JimmyK4542 - I am not that knowledgeable in math. I guess I will have to google the Taylor series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a generating function is the best way to get the closed form for this equation. The recurrence you have defined gives the [Catalan numbers](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C2%2C5%2C14%2C42%2C132%2C429%2C1430%2C4862&language=english&go=Search) which is a sequence of numbers that come up a lot in combinatorics.

You can see one decently explained proof of the recurrence [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#First_proof).